# Count the number of specific values in multiple columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame:

```
A    B    C    D     E

12  4.5  6.1   BUY  NaN
12  BUY  BUY   5.6  NaN
BUY  4.5  6.1  BUY  NaN
12  4.5  6.1   0    NaN
```

I want to count the number of times 'BUY' appears in each row. Intended result:

```
A    B    C    D     E   score

12  4.5  6.1   BUY  NaN    1
12  BUY  BUY   5.6  NaN    2
15  4.5  6.1  BUY   NaN    1
12  4.5  6.1   0    NaN    0
```

I have tried the following but it simply gives 0 for all the rows:

```
df['score'] = df[df == 'BUY'].sum(axis=1)
```

Note that BUY can only appear in B, C, D, E columns.

I tried to find the solution online but shockingly found none.

Little help will be appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could use `apply` with `list.count`:

```
df['score'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.tolist().count('BUY'), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C    D   E  score
0   12  4.5  6.1  BUY NaN      1
1   12  BUY  BUY  5.6 NaN      2
2  BUY  4.5  6.1  BUY NaN      2
3   12  4.5  6.1    0 NaN      0
```

Answer (score 7):

You can compare and then sum:

```
df['score'] = (df[['B','C','D','E']] == 'BUY').sum(axis=1)
```

This sums up all the booleans and you get the correct result.

---

When you do `df[df == 'BUY']`, you are just replacing anything which is not `BUY` with `np.nan` and then taking sum over axis=1 doesnot work since all you have left in your result is `np.nan` and the `'BUY'` string. Hence you get all 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `apply` with `lambda` over axis=1. This picks up each row at a time as a series. You can use the condition `[row == 'BUY']` to filter the row and then count the number of 'BUY' using `len()`

```
df['score'] = df.apply(lambda row: len(row[row == 'BUY']), axis=1)
print(df)
```

```
     A    B    C    D   E  score
0   12  4.5  6.1  BUY NaN      1
1   12  BUY  BUY  5.6 NaN      2
2  BUY  4.5  6.1  BUY NaN      2
3   12  4.5  6.1    0 NaN      0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
df['score'] = np.count_nonzero(df == 'BUY', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
      A   B   C   D   E score
0    12 4.5 6.1 BUY NaN     1
1    12 BUY BUY 5.6 NaN     2
2   BUY 4.5 6.1 BUY NaN     2
3    12 4.5 6.1   0 NaN     0
```